# typo3 FE image links with securedl

Tags: typo3

We recently moved a working installation of our typo3 website to another server and now some images are displayed wrong. They are being resized (displayed smaller than they actually are) and the anchor tag has this source:

```
src="/index.php?eID=tx_nawsecuredl&u=0&g=0&t=138......b&file=fileadmin/templates/../images/clear.gif"
```

As you can see, we use the naw_securedl extension. When I remove everything of the link until fileadmin (/index.php?eID=tx_nawsecuredl&u=0&g=0&t=138......b&file=) the image works, but of course this is not the sense of securedl.

Does anyone know a solution for this? I tried to figure out that is could be the setting "linkFormat" which is currently set to

```
/index.php?eID=tx_nawsecuredl&u=###FEUSER###&g=###FEGROUPS###&t=###TIMEOUT###&hash=###HASH###&file=###FILE###
```

and I updated the .htaccess file but it doesn't change anything...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is "fileadmin/templates/../images/clear.gif" an value which is not working? Or is that only an example. If the files have specialcharacters, it could depend on filesystem utf8/latin1. And check in Install Tool if Image-Resizing works.

Comment: The image link is exactly like that and it is working, but is just being resized, I don't know why. Image-Resizing works.

Comment: Resized to what size exactly? As far as I know does naw_securedl not proceed any gm/im operations on images. Maybe there's another extension present on the new system that's interfering with the file handling...